# Next JS project deployment on local machine giving this error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have cloned an empty NextJS project from GitHub [only have initial project setup] and then I simply did:

```
npm i
npm run dev
```

At localhost:3000, I am continually facing this:
[image]

It seems something related to next or some other dependency. Does anyone has any idea why is it so? or what steps could I opt to resolve this?

Comment: Where does `MainData` come from? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Check if "MainData" variable is initialized and is array on first render and if not try wrapping it with some conditional like to delay rendering the list

```js
{MainData ? MainData.map(data => ...) : <p>Loading...</p>}
```